# What does a second set of index brackets after a data frame notation in r do?

Tags: r

```
df[2,][which(df[1,]!="")]
```

I understand that the above line outputs values from the second row of the dataframe where the corresponding first row isn't empty.

What exactly is happening when you put another set of brackets after the first set of indexing brackets? 
What is another way to get the same output as the above line?

I am new to R. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just merging two lines together:

```
tmp=df[2,]
tmp[which(df[1,]!="")]
```

Another way to go is

```
df[2, which(df[1,]!="")]
```